# mrt add router not working

Tags: node.js, meteor, ubuntu-12.04, meteorite

i am just reading the "DiscoverMeteor" book but the command specified in routing capter `mrt add router`shows some error for me

mrt add router

```
smart.json changed.. installing from smart.json
✓ router
tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.5.4.1
✓ page-js-ie-support
tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js-ie-support.git#v1.3.5
✓ HTML5-History-API
tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-HTML5-History-API.git#v4.0.0

Done installing smart packages

Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
=> Errors while scanning packages:

While building package router:
error: Can't install npm dependencies. Are you connected to the internet?
```

all other examples up to routing chapter working perfectly
currently i using ubuntu 12.04

how i install router ?
pls help me

Comment: In any case, the `meteor-router` is no more maintened. The new recommanded router is called iron-router and you can install it with `mrt add iron-router`. The API is different thought.

Comment: when i run examples/simple-routed-app of  meteor-router using mrt command
it's shows error => 
Stand back while Meteorite does its thing

Done installing smart packages

Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!

[[[[[ ~/Desktop/meteor-router-master/examples/simple-routed-app ]]]]]

Initializing mongo database... this may take a moment.
router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...
=> Errors prevented startup:

While building package router:
error: Can't install npm dependencies. Are you connected to the internet?

=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.`

Comment: Try again, NPM was having server issues earlier today. It seems better now - http://status.npmjs.org/ but check their twitter for better updates https://twitter.com/npmjs

Comment: Getting `iron-router: updating npm dependencies -- connect...` - seems the Npm registry is down.